# "psql: could not connect to server" on OSX: no postmaster.pid to delete

Tags: postgresql

This weekend, I upgraded OSX Catalina (to 10.15.4) and XCode (from 11.2 to 11.4). I also ran `brew upgrade`, which may have upgraded Postgres, though I'm not sure. Anyway, I currently have Postgres 11.4 installed.

But now I can't connect to Postgres:

```
% brew services stop postgresql
% brew services start postgresql
% psql 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've read all the answers suggesting deleting `postmaster.pid`, but there's no `postmaster.pid` file that I can find to delete - not in `/usr/local/var/postgres` or anywhere else.

What should I do?

UPDATE: If I try to start with `pg_ctl` (rather than `brew services`) then I see this error:

```
% pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres
waiting for server to start....2020-04-14 12:20:36.279 BST [99028] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2020-04-14 12:20:36.279 BST [99028] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-04-14 12:20:36.280 BST [99028] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-04-14 12:20:36.290 BST [99028] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
2020-04-14 12:20:36.290 BST [99028] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _RAND_cleanup
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/bin/postgres
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _RAND_cleanup
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/bin/postgres
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

 stopped waiting
```

So I wonder if it could be something to do with libcrypto?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue after upgrading to MacOS 10.15.5, but with postgres 9.4.18
This version indeed has a dependency with libssl.1.0.0.dylib.

```
> otool -L '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.4/9.4.18/bin/postgres'
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.4/9.4.18/bin/postgres:
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
```

What fixed it was to upgrade postgres.

```
> brew upgrade 'postgresql@9.4'
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
postgresql@9.4 9.4.18 -> 9.4.26
```

Then

```
> otool -L '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.4/9.4.26/bin/postgres'
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.4/9.4.26/bin/postgres:
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
```

And starting postgres is now OK.

```
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.4 start
```